# SAP adapter: disasembler problem "Unexpected end of stream while looking for:..."

Tags: adapter, biztalk, idoc

Use WCF-SAP binding in WCF-Custom adapter, ReceiveIDOCFormat is set to 'String', in the pipeline component, we wrap and call a flat file disassembler to disassemble the SAP request to XML and process it later. We also have a log compnent which will log the SAP raw message prior to disassembler (the string version) to database (streaming way using CForwardOnlyStream)

Here is the problem, during the UAT testing with SAP, we find occasionally the flat file disassembler is complaining 'Unexpected end of stream while looking for:....', when we inspect the SAP message sent over the wire, we find the SAP request only contains the header (EDI_DC40), with emty content after that. What makes me worry is , when we go into SAP, resubmit the failed message using transaction WE19, disassembler has no problem parsing it.

I am totally lost, can someone please sugguest how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks a million!!

Comment: Is there any (event)log entry on the SAP side indicating any problems with message transmission? I'm not familiar with the EDI_DC40 message format but I suppose messages will not get too big to violate WCF send or receive size settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably I found the problem now, SAP guys added a field, what I used to do (which I think is right but it may be the flaw) is, I didn't regenerate the schema, instead, I just manually added the field in Visual Studio and set the field length based on IDOC description.

I regenerated the IDOC using the WCF wizard, it seems it is not as same as added a field in visual studio, I just deployed this schema and hope it will address the problem, I'll post my findings later if it worked